# Save an object containing functions to a .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, require

Say I have an object like below:

```
let obj = {
    mounted: (value) => {
        return "Yeesss" + value;
    },
    a: "123123",
    c: {
        d: (key) => {
            return key + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I can stringify the object and its functions like so:

```
let objString = JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
    if(typeof value === "function") return "[Function]" + value;
    return value;
});
```

which will then be like:

```
{
    "mounted":"[Function](value) => {\n        return \"Yeesss\" + value;\n    }",
    "a":"123123",
    "c":{
        "d":"[Function](key) => {\n            return key + 1;\n        }"
    }
}
```

I can save this string to a .json file and read it and parse it like below which will give me back the same object:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(objString, (key, value) => {
    if(typeof value === "string" && value.startsWith("[Function]")){
        value = value.substring(10);
        value = eval(value);
        return value;
    }
    return value;
});
```

What I want to know is how can I save that object in the beginning with `fs` in a .js file in the following format:

```
module.exports = {
    mounted: (value) => {
        return "Yeesss" + value;
    },
    a: "123123",
    c: {
        d: (key) => {
            return key + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

So that I can require it and use it some other time in the future.

Comment: Create a class definition in its own module (which you can freely use in other projects).  Create a constructor or a method for that class that accepts a set of data that it will use to initialize the instance data of an object of that class.  You keep code and data separate.  Code (as a class definition) is in a reusable module.  The data can be stored anywhere (database, JSON file, text file, etc...) and you can then just create an instance of the Class and then call a method, passing it your data and the method will initialize the object from your data.

Comment: I don't understand the use case for this. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by doing this - like what problem does this solve for you? Why not just create an .js file and save the module code to it, which you can require at any time?

Comment: @MattOestreich I'm kinda reinventing bundlers like webpack with vue-loader. The object is a dynamic vue component that hasn't been initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

1. Use `JSON.stringify()` with the function-handling to produce a string.
2. Search and replace the function-values with an dequoted and unescaped value.
3. Add module prefix.

```js
let obj = {
    mounted: (value) => {
        return "Yeesss" + value;
    },
    a: "123123",
    c: {
        d: (key) => {
            return key + 1;
        }
    }
};

let json = JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    return '[FUNCTION]' + value;
  }
  return value;
}, '    ');

let moduleJavascript = json.replace(/"(\[FUNCTION])?((?:\\.|[^\\"])*)"(:)?/g, (match, group1, group2, group3) => {
    if (group1) return JSON.parse('"' + group2 + '"');
    if (group3 && /^\w+$/.test(group2)) return group2 + ':';
    return match;
});

moduleJavascript = 'module.exports = ' + moduleJavascript + ';';

console.log(moduleJavascript);
```

---

If this gets too complicated, you might consider using a code generation tool. [EJS](https://ejs.co/) might fit your needs.

Template:

```
module.exports = {
    mounted: (value) => {
        return "Yeesss" + value;
    },
    a: <%= locals.avalue %>,
    c: {
        d: (key) => {
            return key + 1;
        }
    }
};
```

And call with:

```
let ejs = require('ejs'),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('template.ejs', (err, templateText) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let moduleJavascript = ejs.render(templateText, {
        // Arguments into the template
        avalue: "123123"
    }, {
        // To make <%= %> escape JavaScript instead of HTML
        escape: JSON.stringify
    });
});
```

Comment: While this might technically do what the OP asked, I rather doubt this is really the best solution to the real problem as it seems mostly like a big hack.  Code should be stored in a reusable module where it can freely be used in lots of places.  Data can then be saved separately (database, JSON file, etc...) and then you create an object from the Class definition and then initialize it with the data.

Comment: @jfriend00 the reason that I can't store code and data separately is because this object is a vue component that hasn't been initialized yet and it's dynamically generated.

Comment: @DarrenRahnemoon - That doesn't make any sense to me.  Are you writing code programmatically?  You can ALWAYS load code from one place, load data from another and combine the two at runtime.  There's no need to store code and data intermingled in the same file.  It seems to me that you just don't understand what your options are and are thus asking for a solution that is almost never used and is generally not considered a good way to do things.